# list vs UserList and dict vs UserDict

Tags: python, list, dictionary, subclass

Coding this day, which of the above is preferred and recommended (both in Python 2 and 3) for subclassing?

I read that `UserList` and `UserDict` have been introduced because in the past `list` and `dict` couldn't be subclassed, but since this isn't an issue anymore, is it encouraged to use them?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Depending on your usecase, these days you'd either subclass `list` and `dict` directly, or you can subclass [`collections.MutableSequence` and `collections. MutableMapping`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections-abstract-base-classes); these options are there *in addition* to using the `User*` objects.

The `User*` objects have been moved to the `collections` module in Python 3; but any code that used those in the Python 2 stdlib has been replaced with the `collections.abc` abstract base classes. Even in Python 2, `UserList` and `UserDict` are augmented `collections.*` implementations, adding methods `list` and `dict` provide beyond the basic interface.

The `collections` classes make it clearer what must be implemented for your subclass to be a complete implementation, and also let you implement smaller subsets (such as `collections.Mapping`, implementing a read-only mapping, or `collections.Sequence` for a tuple-like object).

The `User*` implementations should be used when you need to implement everything beyond the basic interface too; e.g. if you need to support addition, sorting, reversing and counting just like `list` does.

For anything else you are almost always better off using the `collections` abstract base classes as a basis; the built-in types are optimised for speed and are not that subclass-friendly. For example, you'll need to override just about every method on `list` where normally a new `list` is returned, to ensure your subclass is returned instead.

Only if you need to build code that *insists* on using a `list` or `dict` object (tested by using `isinstance()` is subclassing the types an option to consider. This is why `collections.OrderedDict` is a subclass of `dict`, for example.

Comment: And what difference does subclassing each of them bring to subclassing their counterpart? Why should I use `list` in favor of `collections.Sequence` or vice-versa?

Comment: @AndreiHorak:- Just to add you may check one issue which will help you understand more: http://bugs.python.org/issue5402

Comment: Despite OP's satisfaction, I don't think this answers the question as asked - which appears to be about choosing between e.g. subclassing `list` directly or subclassing `collections.UserList`, regardless of whether the ABCs would be a better choice.

Answer (score 4):

**No** they are not encouraged anymore. You should not use the  UserDict class as it is [deprecated](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3108/). The docs says you can just subclass `dict` directly.  The `userdict` module is gone in Python 3.0

Comment: In the link you've provided there is `Moved to the 'collections' module.` specified. If they are not encouraged anymore, why were they kept in the latest versions? What do they bring different than the standard types?

Comment: @AndreiHorak:- From Python version 2.6, it is recommended to use `collections.MutableMapping` and `collections.Sequence` instead.

Comment: @AndreiHorak: they are not really deprecated as it turns out the classes have their uses; it is easier to subclass `UserList` and get sorting and (in Python 2) slicing to work correctly vs having to override everything on the `list` type.

Comment: No. As [the docs say](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.UserDict), the `User*` classes can be easier to work with when access to the underlying data structure is needed because it is accessible as an attribute.