# Initialising list superclass - self parameter needed sometimes but not others?

Tags: python-3.x, initialization, subclass

This is from the book head first python (pg 208 chapter 6). Initially I saw an example in the book of the initialisation of the subclass as so:

```
class AthleteList(list):
    def __init__(self, a_times=[]):
        list.__init__([])
        self.extend(a_times)
```

When I came to writing my own version I thought I could skip the `extend` step:

```
class AthleteList(list):
    def __init__(self, a_times=[]):
        list.__init__(a_times)
```

When it comes to printing the list:

```
test = AthleteList([1,2,3])
print(test)
```

The output is `[]`, so there is something wrong with the initialisation. [When searching around](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36557009/explicit-passing-of-self-when-calling-super-classs-init-in-python), in every case I found I saw it necessary to initialise the superclass by explicitly passing `self`:

```
class AthleteList(list):
    def __init__(self, a_times=[]):
        list.__init__(self, a_times)
```

Which makes more sense: the list superclass needs the object itself passed as an argument so that it can initialise its list values. Except why wasn't `self` needed in the very first example (which does actually work)? Even if I am initialising it with an empty list I still surely need to pass the `self` object so that `self`'s list is made empty. I don't even need to initialise it to the empty list first, it seems to do it by default, and I can just extend later:

```
class AthleteList(list):
    def __init__(self, a_times=[]):
        self.extend(a_times)
```

Comment: You saw `def __init__(self, a_times=[])` in a book? If so you should consider changing a book. http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/python/3553/common-pitfalls/12258/mutable-default-argument#t=201612281429272429582

Comment: As I see it, `AthleteList` is of type `list` and therefore `[]` is used instead of `self` to initialize the parent object (which constructor does not need any arguments). But in my eyes this is very, very unclean. Try `list.__init__([1, 2, 3])` in your first code snippet and create the object with an emtpy `a_times`. The values will not be shown.

Comment: inheriting from a list is easier with [`UserList`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html?highlight=namedtuple#collections.UserList). here everything works as expcected.

Comment: For reference, in case anyone's interested, the page in question is [here](https://cdn.pbrd.co/images/fhx27wo1y.png). The book's treatment of inheritance beyond that page is sketchy to say the least, and I have to agree with @DeepSpace that OP should look to [other, better resources](http://sopython.com/wiki/What_tutorial_should_I_read%3F).

Answer (score 1):

this is probably the safest way to subclass `list`; use [`UserList`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html?highlight=namedtuple#userlist-objects) as base class and things work as expected:

```
from collections import UserList

class AthleteList(UserList):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

athlete_list = AthleteList((1, 2, 3))
print(athlete_list)  # -> [1, 2, 3]
```

that admittedly does not answer all your questions but may be a starting point.

here is a more in-depth answer about that: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25464724/4954037 .