# |= vs update with a subclass of collections.abc.Set

Tags: python

I need to subclass `set` so I subclassed `collections.abc.Set`, as suggested here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6698723/211858.
Please find my simple implementation below.
It essentially wraps a set of integers.

I generate list of 10,000 `MySet` instances consisting of 100 random integers.
I would like to take the union of these wrapped sets.
I have two implementations below.
For some reason, the first using `update` is very fast, yet the second using `|=` is slow.
The `tqdm` wrapper is to conduct nonrigorous benchmarks.
Is there some way to correct the definition of the class to fix this performance issue?
Thanks!

I'm on Python 3.10.5.

```
from collections.abc import Iterable, Iterator, Set

from tqdm import tqdm


class MySet(Set):
    def __init__(self, integers: Iterable[int]) -> None:
        self.data: set[int] = set(integers)

    def __len__(self) -> int:
        return len(self.data)

    def __iter__(self) -> Iterator[int]:
        return iter(self.data)

    def __contains__(self, x: object) -> bool:
        if isinstance(x, int):
            return x in self.data
        else:
            raise NotImplemented

    def my_func(self):
        ...

    def my_other_func(self):
        ...


# %%
import random

# Make some mock data
my_sets: list[MySet] = [
    MySet(random.sample(range(1_000_000), 100)) for _ in range(10_000)
]

# %%
universe: set[int] = set()
universe2: set[int] = set()

# %%
# Nearly instant
for my_set in tqdm(my_sets):
    universe.update(my_set)

# %%
# Takes well over 5 minutes on my laptop
for my_set in tqdm(my_sets):
    universe2 |= my_set
```

Comment: They are both pretty much instantaneous for me (tested on Python 3.8). (I had to replace the import with `from typing import Iterable, Iterator, Set, List` for it to work, so I assume your Python version is different)

Comment: @Amadan Thank you. I'm on 3.10, but I'm able to replicate your observation from changing `collection.abc` to `typing`. I think `Set` in `typing` refers to the built-in Python set class (https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.10/Lib/typing.py#L2136), while `Set` in `collections.abc` refers to a different class (https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.10/Lib/_collections_abc.py#L573). I'm still a bit fuzzy on the difference.  The link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57132624/why-there-is-no-userset-class-defined-in-python is probably helpful. the UserSet implementation fails a mypy check.

Comment: `typing` classes exist to specify types for the built-in classes. I was getting `TypeError: 'type' object is not subscriptable` for `set[int]`, but `Set[int]` works. However I think something changed in 3.10 (PEP 649? not sure) that makes your code work without an error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Conclusion:** The way to add the least code is to implement the `__ior__` method.

What happens when there is no implementation:

1. When binary inplace or operation is performed for the first time, because `universe2` is `set` and `my_set` is `MySet`, `set` cannot recognize the `MySet` class, so the binary inplace or operation will degenerate into a binary or operation.
2. As in point 1, the binary or operation of `set` will fail, so Python will try to call the `__ror__` method of `MySet`.
3. Because `MySet` has no `__ror__` method, Python will fall back to the `collections.abc.Set`. The `__ror__` method of it is the same as the `__or__` method and returns the result of type `MySet`. You can find it in the _collections_abc.py file:

```
class Set(Collection):
    ...
    @classmethod
    def _from_iterable(cls, it):
        '''Construct an instance of the class from any iterable input.

        Must override this method if the class constructor signature
        does not accept an iterable for an input.
        '''
        return cls(it)
    ...
    def __or__(self, other):
        if not isinstance(other, Iterable):
            return NotImplemented
        chain = (e for s in (self, other) for e in s)
        return self._from_iterable(chain)

    __ror__ = __or__
    ...
```

4. For the subsequent binary inplace or operation, because the first `__ror__` operation changes `universe2` to `MySet` type and neither `MySet` nor `collections.abc.Set` has the `__ior__` method, so the `collections.abc.Set.__or__` function will be called repeatly, and a copy will be made per loop. This is the root cause of the slow speed of the second loop. Therefore, as long as the `__ior__` method is implemented to avoid copying of subsequent operations, the performance will be greatly improved.

**Suggestions for better implementation:** The abstract class `collections.abc.Set` represents an immutable set. For this reason, it does not implement the inplace operation method. If you need your subclass to support inplace operation, you should consider inheriting `collections.abc.MutableSet` and implementing the `add` and `discard` abstract methods. `Mutableset` implements the inplace operation methods such as `__ior__` through these two abstract methods (of course, it is still not efficient compared with the built-in `set`, so it is better to implement them by yourself):

```
class MutableSet(Set):
    ...
    def __ior__(self, it):
        for value in it:
            self.add(value)
        return self
    ...
```

**Correction:** There are some mistakes in the old answers. Here we want to correct them. I hope those who have read the old answers can see here:

Mistacke 1:

> If necessary, you can also implement the `__ior__` method, but it is not recommended to implement it separately when neither `__or__` nor `__ror__` methods are implemented, because Python will try to call the `__ior__` method when it cannot find their implementation, which will make the behavior of non inplace operations become inplace operations, and may lead to unexpected results.

Correction: the binary or operation does not call the `__ior__` method when the `__or__` and `__ror__` are missing.

Mistacke 2:

> Generally speaking, binary operations between instances of different types may expect to get the type results of left operands, such as `set` and `frozenset`:
>
> ```
> >>> {1} | frozenset({2})
> {1, 2}
> >>> frozenset({2}) | {1}
> frozenset({1, 2})
> ```

Correction: This is not always true. For example, the `__ror__` operation of `collections.abc.Set` also returns its subtype instead of the type of the left operand.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed and clear explanation. Suppose I have the toy example: I want a subclass of `set[int]`, that has an additional method that returns the min of the integers. Would you suggest I just subclass `set[int]` with the additional method, or should I continue along this approach. Your explanation makes clear some of the subtleties of working with `collections`.

Comment: @hwong557 I think it depends more on your preference if you just simply package `min(self.data)`.

Comment: @hwong557 There are some errors in the original answers. I have deleted them and given better implementation suggestions.