Strange behaviour of python ```@property```
I have a class which is a set of words:
import math
from typing import Self

FREQUENCIES: dict[str, float] = {}
FREQUENCIES['trial'] = 0.023
FREQUENCIES['raise'] = 0.124

def entropy(probability: float) -> float:
  if probability == 0.0: return 0.0
  return -probability*math.log(probability)/math.log(2.0)

class Word(str):
  def __new__(cls, value: str = 'aaaaa') -> Self:
    value = value.strip().lower()
    if not re.match(r'[a-z]{5}', value): raise ValueError(f'"{value}" does not follow the pattern [a-z]{5}!')
    return super().__new__(cls, value)
  def __init__(self, value: str = 'aaaaa') -> None:
    self.frequency = FREQUENCIES[value]

class Universe(set[Word]):
  def __init__(self) -> None:
    super().__init__(set())
    self.frequency = 0.0
    self.statistics: dict[int, dict[str, float]] = {}
    self.updated = True
  def __iadd__(self, word: Word) -> Self:
    if word in self: return self
    self.updated = False
    self.add(word)
    return self
  @property
  def uncertainty(self) -> float:
    if not self.updated:
       self.frequency = sum(word.frequency for word in self)
       self.statistics = {i: {chr(letter): sum(wordle.frequency for wordle in self if wordle[i] == chr(letter)) for letter in range(ord('a'), ord('z')+1)} for i in range(len(Word()))}
       self.updated = True
    return sum(sum(entropy(letterFrequency/self.frequency) for letterFrequency in self.statistics[position].values()) for position in self.statistics) 

When I add (with +=) an element to it I make sure I make the self.updated dirty.
This is the tricky part. Originally, I created the @property to calculate the uncertainty of the Universe.
I would like to use this something like:
universe = Universe()
universe += Word('trial')
universe += Word('raise')
print(f'My universe has {len(universe)} words and an uncertainty of {universe.uncertainty} bits."

The odd side effect I seem to noticed is that self.updated is ALWAYS True (i can see it on the debugger window)!!!
If I remove @property the code runs exactly like I would expect it to (self.updated only becomes True after I explicitly call self.uncertainty()).
What am I missing here?
SOLUTION
I am using Visual Studio Code and when the variable universe appears on the debugger window, its @property self.uncertainty shows up on the debugger as a variable (showing its value). That means the Visual Studio Code debugger is calling the @property every step of my debugging and therefore it is setting  self.updated to True.
That also explains why the code "works" when I remove the @property: the debugger does NOT call self.uncertainty() on its own (which sets self.update to True)

Please provide a [mcve], including the def of Word and how a using code might be using Universe.

you must provide a [mcve]

note, propertys may be run if you use something like help(obj) on an instance of your Universe object. As an aside, I would suggest using a collections.UserSet instead of inheriting from set directly, if you actually want to be able to control updates without overriding every possible method that updates the set (which you would need to do if you inherit from set)

Also, FWIW, I believe self.statistics = dict[int, dict[str, float]] = {} should be self.statistics: dict[int, dict[str, float]] = {}

Oh, yes @DeepSpace! Let me correct the code!

@juanpa.arrivillaga There is no UserSet  :) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57132624/why-there-is-no-userset-class-defined-in-python

@DeepSpace and @juanpa.arrivillaga, let me add the code for class Word (it just a standardised five-letter word).

@DeepSpace d'oh!

@Nuno that isn't what we asked for, we asked for a [mcve].

also, nevermind about that issue with help, I was confusing some other bug with this situation with property (IIRC, it only applied to methods that were decorated with both property and @classmethod)

looking at the code you posted, you are running uncertainty, so of course, it will set self.updated = True... but it isn't clear when or what is unexpected here

@juanpa.arrivillaga, I have added the full minimal code.

ok, thank you! can you explain exactly what the issue is with the ode you provide? What is the output you expected, and how does it differ from the output you are seeing?

@juanpa.arrivillaga, the problem I am having is that self.updatedis True even before I get to that print.

so, you say, "If I remove @property the code runs exactly like I would expect it to." .... but that means you expected your code to raise an AttributeError, is that what you mean?

Your "full minimal code" contains several syntax errors. We should be able to copy and paste the code you post without having to make any edits. Help us help you.

In any case, if I fill in the missing imports, and run the first three lines of the driver code, and then print(universe.updated) it is False. not True. Sso still no [mcve].

@juanpa.arrivillaga, the problem was on the Visual Studio Code debugger! When I setup a function as a @property, the debugger treats it as an instance variable and automatically calls the function! That's why I was "always" seeing self.updated set to True!!!

SOLUTION I am using Visual Studio Code and when the variable universe appears on the debugger window, its @property self.uncertainty shows up on the debugger as a variable (showing its value). That means the Visual Studio Code debugger is calling the @property every step of my debugging and therefore it is setting  self.updated to True. That also explains why the code "works" when I remove the @property: the debugger does NOT call self.uncertainty() on its own (which sets self.update to True)
