# How to call __set_item__ at dictionary initialisation?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

Below is a class `MyDict` that inherits from `dict`.  What I want to
do is basically to perform some operation each time a key of a
`MyDict` object is assigned a value.  So `__setitem__` is my friend
here:

```py
class MyDict(dict):
    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        print(f'key {key} set to {value}')
        super().__setitem__(key, value)

m = MyDict()
m[0] = 'hello'   # prints "0 set to hello"
m[1] = 'world!'  # prints "1 set to world!"
```

This is great but now if I do this, `__setitem__` is not called anymore.

```py
m = MyDict({0: 'hello', 1: 'world!'})
```

I could of course overload `__init__` to solve my problem but is
there a simpler solution?

Besides, as I understand the `dict.__init__` help message:

```py
 |  dict(iterable) -> new dictionary initialized as if via:
 |      d = {}
 |      for k, v in iterable:
 |          d[k] = v
```

`__setitem__` should be called in my example.  Have I misunderstood
something?

Comment: m[0] = 'hello' is not making any entry. Just print.  where as m = MyDict({0: 'hello', 1: 'world!'}) is making entry.

Comment: @Epsi95: many thanks for pointing that mistake.  Fixed!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should subclass `UserDict`:

```
from collections import UserDict

class MyDict(UserDict):
    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        print(f'key {key} set to {value}')

m = MyDict({0: 'hello', 1: 'world!'})
```

Outputs

```
key 0 set to hello
key 1 set to world!
```

Related questions: [Subclass dict: UserDict, dict or ABC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7148419/subclass-dict-userdict-dict-or-abc) and [list vs UserList and dict vs UserDict](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25464647/list-vs-userlist-and-dict-vs-userdict/25464724)

Comment: super().__setitem__(key, value)

Comment: Many thanks for the answer and the links.  I did not know of `UserDict`.